# PHP, how to get the Array Key in Single Dimensional Array.

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, array-key

In PHP I create an array of key value pairs like this, how to I get "mykey"?

```
$arr = array("mykey"=>"myvalue");
```

I know the code below will work, but I am interested to know if there is a language construct in PHP that allows me to this in a easier fashion.

```
foreach($arr as $key=>$value){
  $result = $key;
  break;
}
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just Use [key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php)  if you dealing with one element and [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) with arrays with multiple values.

Example

```
$arr = array("mykey"=>"myvalue");
var_dump(key($arr));
```

Or

```
 var_dump(array_keys($arr));
```

Output

```
string 'mykey' (length=5)
```

and

```
array
  0 => string 'mykey' (length=5)
```

Answer (score 1):

**try this**

you can use **array_keys** function in php

```
<?php
$array = array(0 => 100, "color" => "red");
print_r(array_keys($array));

$array = array("blue", "red", "green", "blue", "blue");
print_r(array_keys($array, "blue"));

$array = array("color" => array("blue", "red", "green"),
               "size"  => array("small", "medium", "large"));
print_r(array_keys($array));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `array_keys`, here's the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)